# How do I get this layout?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, reporting-services, multiple-tables

I have an SSRS report that I'm using multiple datasets (each in the form of stored procedures) to extract information for. The application that this report will reside in is used to enter audit information along with files. What I'm hoping to accomplish is a report layout similar to this:[image: Desired Report Layout].

Since I'm dealing with a lot of 1-to-many relationships and tables, I thought it would be best to use multiple datasets rather than write a stored procedure that joins these tables, but maybe I'm wrong?

Can anyone recommend how to accomplish this layout? I've tried using Subreports embedded into a data matrix that displays the Issue description, issue images, action description, and action file fields but the output isn't very nice (see below) and I've been told that data matrices are better suited for numeric data rather than text data.

[image: Matrix Output]

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look [here](http://jaysonseaverbi.blogspot.fr/2013/12/ssrs-recursive-parent.html)

It seems like it has been published for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The concept of SSRS Recursive Parent definitely seems like it would work for my situation. 

I guess my next question would be how do I construct the proper stored procedure? I'm wondering if creating a temporary table & populating the fields in the SP would be the answer since I'm dealing with extracting data from so many tables? Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: It will depend. Like that I can't tell you if I don't know more about your tables involved, row volume expected (most important). If you estimate row volume too important, so use intermediate table which would be filled on need (daily, each time report is launched...).